# Power Apps multiple cascading drop downs from SharePoint List Choices Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a relatively simple scenario which I am trying to implement in Power Apps, but can't seem to make it work.

I have **2 drop downs** which source values will be from a **SharePoint list** with 2 columns **Region**  and **Department**. Both these columns are ***Choice*** type columns

[image]

**Department** dropdown will depend on **Region** selected

1. Region dropdown *Items* property

   `Choices([@MySharePointList].Region)`
2. Department dropdown *Items* property

   `Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value).Department`

I think it filters correctly, however they are *Records*. As a result, the dropdown has items but are shown as empty items.

How do I retrieve the actual value of the **Department** for this dropdown?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm if you using dropdown or combobox control for department and region? Is this a standalone canvas app or Power Apps customized list form?

Comment: Standalone canvas app. Dropdown control for both. Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer given below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula for Department drop down **Items** property:

```
Distinct(Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value), Department.Value)
```

**SharePoint list**:

[image]

**Power Apps output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works. Funny, it seems that we need to use `Distinct` outside `Filter` for this case to work. For example using `Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value).Department.Value` does not work. Was wondering if you know why?

Comment: items property of drop down control expects a table/array input. So, we are creating array of departments using distinct values from `Department.Value`.

Comment: Understand, however I think `Filter` return a table as well? A table of 'Records' in my case (as per screenshot). Hence shouldn't it work with `.Department.Value` on `Filter`? Or am I missing something

Comment: `Value` property of drop down control works only with simple values such as text, number, dates, etc. While `Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value).Department` returns nested/complex objects which are not supported. When you try to use it, you will get warning/error in formula bar.

Comment: Understood that `.Department` are complex objects. But was wondering why we can't use `.Value` directly on `Department`, example:`Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value).Department.Value`. This gives a syntax error.

Comment: Maybe Power Apps formula unable to understand & return table/array of department values just by adding `.Value` after the department array because its complex object nature.